# Meaning of logic operation " a' "

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I have found the following expression:

```
c = (a'.b)
```

what does it mean?

I know `a.b` is `a and b` (Boolean Algebra), but what does `a'.b`  mean?

Comment: a' is the same as "not a", the negation of a, so a'.b means "not a and b"

Comment: ErikR - as that is an essentially complete reply would you like to post it as an answer.

Comment: @ErikR does it mean that `c` is not equal to `a and b`? ( `and` is first?)

Comment: Don't say *and is first*, that's confusing. Actually the NOT comes first. So: c = NOT(a) AND b

Comment: @AnnaKoroleva I'm not sure what you're asking. The expression `a and b` could be equal to `a' and b` if `b` is false. But as formulas they are not the same.

Comment: @AnnaKoroleva the prime binds to the a, not to the whole expression, so it's ((not a) and b)

Comment: This is the wrong site for pure math questions. If you are just asking what a certain math notation means, you should be using one of the math sites. In case you are asking how to translate the boolean math expression to logic gates, truth tables or to C code etc then it's on-topic here.

Answer (score 6):

\$'\$ is complement operator in that context.

\$A'\$ is also equivalent to \$\overline A\$.  It signifies a negation on boolean variable \$A\$, ie., \$\text{not } A\$.

So the expression in your question will become:-
$$C=(\text{not }A) \text { and } B$$